# is it possible to have different action for every pathPrefix in deep linking android?

Tags: android, react-native, deep-linking, android-app-links

I am working on React Native Project and I have a problem in deep linking Android. I have two different pathPrefix. Let say:

`<data android:pathPrefix="/query" />`

and

`<data android:pathPrefix="/transaction" />`

What I want are:

1. If I click `https://my.domain/query` the native modal appears and give me an option to open it in app or browser
2. But if i click `https://my.domain/transaction` its automatically direct me to my app without showing any modal

I have read this https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations to solve number two and I already did. But didn't work like I want.

I already tried:

1. Make two different activity. `MainActivity` and `SecondActivity`. in Main, i use prefix `query` and in SecondActivity, I use prefix `transaction` and in this activity, my intent-filter has `android:autoVerify="true"` to make the App Links works.
2. I made one activity, but I have 2 `inten-filter`. One with `android:autoVerify="true"` and another one without it.

Both have the same result. It direct me to my app automatically.

My question, it is possible to have that different action? And if so, how to achieve it?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with something like this?

```
<activity ...>

  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="false">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
      android:scheme="https"
      android:host="my.domain"
      android:pathPrefix="query" />
  </intent-filter>

  <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

    <data
      android:scheme="https"
      android:host="my.domain"
      android:pathPrefix="transaction" />

  </intent-filter>

</activity>
```

Comment: what is tools:targetApi="m"? it makes my app error when installing process. it says:  "The prefix "tools" for attribute "tools:targetApi" associated with an element type "intent-filter" is not bound."

Comment: You can remove it. It's a simple warning suppressor. If you want keep it you need to add this line `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` below `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` like here: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/tool-attributes